# Agregar por cada fila en una tabla dos botones, uno para visualizar solo archivo PDF y el otro botón que permita eliminar la fila

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo a programar. He conseguido este código, estoy tratando de agregar dos botones por cada fila ingresado, el primer botón que permita visualizar solo archivo PDF en un visor aparte y el otro botón que permita eliminar la fila. También no reconoce el tipo de archivo rar y el contador de archivos no suma la totalidad de fila que tiene la tabla, de antemano gracias por sus ayuda.

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('myInputFile');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  const files = this.files;
  const result = document.querySelector('#archivosSubidos tbody');
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(insertTd(tr, files[i].name));
    tr.appendChild(insertTd(tr, files[i].size));
    tr.appendChild(insertTd(tr, files[i].type));
    result.appendChild(tr);
  }
});

function insertTd(father, string) {
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerText = string;
  return td;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h3>Subir archivos</h3>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-3 w-75">
      <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Ejemplo de entrada de varios archivos</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="myInputFile" multiple>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped w-75 border" id="archivosSubidos">
    <thead>
      <tr class="bg-info text-white">
        <th scope="col">Nombre archivo</th>
        <th scope="col">Tamaño en Byte</th>
        <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```